# Ionic how to fix "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError" error?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

//html

```
    <span style="margin-left:43%;background-color:rgb(229,229,229);border-
    radius:10%">&nbsp;&nbsp;{{formatEpoch(epoch)}}&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
```

//ts

```
lastdate:any;                    

 formatEpoch(epoch): string {
    if(epoch == this.lastdate){
        return '';
    }else{ 
    this.lastdate =epoch;
    return UtilService.getCalendarDay(epoch);
    }
  }
```

ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: '今天 5:34 PM'. Current value: ''.

How can i fix this error? Please help.

Comment: Remove expression with side effect from template

Comment: Thanks for reply. Would you like to tell more details,please?

Comment: Angular runs two change detection cycles in dev mode. During the first check you change `this.lastdata` so the second check throws error

Comment: read the article that explains the error in depth [Everything you need to know about the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4)

Answer (score 1):

if like in angular, try to use

```
this._changeDetectionRef.detectChanges();
```

at the end of your method, not forgetting to add

```
private _changeDetectionRef : ChangeDetectorRef
```

as parameter of the constructor of the Component owning your method.

See discution [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6005)

Comment: Thank you my friend

Answer (score 0):

**Could you try this**

```
lastdate:any;                    
formatEpoch(epoch): string {
   setTimeout(()=> {
     if(epoch == this.lastdate){
        return '';
     }else{ 
       this.lastdate =epoch;
       return UtilService.getCalendarDay(epoch);
     }
   }, 100);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. but no changes.

Answer (score 0):

the best solution:

```
  import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';

  // ...

  constructor(
    ...
    private _platform:Platform
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.formatEpoch()
    })
  }
```